# How can I start playing an audio file from a certain position with Xamarin MediaManager?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I don't want to play the first 10 seconds of my audio file. The audio file should immediately start playing after the first 10 seconds.
I use the following code to play my audio file but I have not found a way to enter a TimeSpan so that the file starts playing after the first 10 seconds:

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
{
    CrossMediaManager.Current.PlayFromResource("Mysong.m4a");
}
else
{
    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
    {
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("file:///android_asset/Mysong.m4a");
    }
}
```

How can I start playing an audio file from a certain position?

Comment: You need to change the position of a stream.  So read the file into a stream.  Then change offset.  So you should have : CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(stream);

Comment: use `SeekTo(TimeSpan)`

Comment: @jdweng
 How can I read the file into a stream and change the offset?

Comment: Not sure if the play method uses Stream or StreamReader.  They are both under System.IO and the position property changes the offset.

Comment: I don't know how you seek 10s into a compressed audio stream?  As I noted above, CrossMediaManager has a SeekTo method that accepts a TimeSpan

Comment: It works with SeekTo(TimeSpan).